# NSNetServiceBrowser not able to find Apple TV "occasionally"

Tags: ios, bonjour, apple-tv, nsnetservice, nsnetservicebrowser

I am using `NSNetServiceBrowser` to find `NSNetService` of `Apple TV` over `bonjour` connection. Now my code works almost every time. But every once in a while (1 out of 10 times) `NSNetServiceBrowser` is not able to find `NSNetService` of `Apple TV` or taking awful amount of time to find it.

Once `NSNetServiceBrowser` is unable to detect `Apple TV`, I have to restart the `Apple TV` and again everything starts working normally.

I am not able to understand what is the problem and how restarting the `Apple TV` solves it. So I am looking for any guidance or suggestion to pin point the problem.

Code for Apple TV :

```
service = [[NSNetService alloc] initWithDomain:@"" type:@"_test._tcp" name:@"TV ZohoShow" port:0];
[service scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
service.includesPeerToPeer = YES;
if(service)
{
    [service setDelegate:self];
    [service publishWithOptions:NSNetServiceListenForConnections];

}
```

Code for iOS device:

```
[serviceBrowser scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
serviceBrowser.includesPeerToPeer = YES;
[serviceBrowser setDelegate:self];
[serviceBrowser searchForServicesOfType:@"_test._tcp" inDomain:@""];
```

**UPDATE**: It never happens when I try the connection between two iOS devices. I get the connection 100/100 times in that case. But as soon as I introduce Apple TV, I start getting those occasions where TV won't be found.